# Pass input and output files desired PATH to a binary in bash

Tags: linux, file, bash, scripting

In a bash script called through shell in some directory ($PWD), there is a line where I need to call an executable located at $PWD/bin so that it reads a input file located at $PWD/inputfiles and the resulting output files are stored in $PWD/output.

Can this be achieved?

PS: Now if I am at

```
cd /home/user
```

I do

```
./run config.inp output.dat
```

with config.inp being at /home/user

config.inp reads files data.txt and lines.txt which are in the same directory.

Now I want to read from /home/user/input and write the output files to /home/user/output

and I try

```
./run input/config.inp
```

it says

```
error, data.txt not found
```

Comment: can you edit your question to show how your command works now, AND **how you  would like it to work**. Good luck.

Comment: Ok, I did it, I hope it gets more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the problem is described, this will do it:

```
bin/executable < inputfiles/input > output/output
```

If the problem is really that `bin/executable` creates files in the *current directory* without allowing the user to specify the input and output files, then it will be a little more complicated. What you would probably want to do instead is:

```
cd output
ln -s ../inputfiles/input
../bin/executable
rm input
```

This will create a symbolic link to `inputfiles/input` from within the `output` directory, and then delete it later. If you want to eliminate the chance of collisions with files in the `output` directory, then you need to create a temporary directory with something like `TMPDIR = $(mktemp -d)`, do everything there, and then copy it back to `$OLDPWD/output`.

Comment: yes, it can read the input file but the first problem is that it can not read the "data.txt" file which is in the "input" directory